# Si... que... pour plusieurs conditions

Tags: grammaire, conditions

J'ai quelques questions sur la construction suivante, dans laquelle on utilise "si" et "que" pour construire une phrase conditionnelle avec plusieurs conditions. Les deux examples ci-dessous sont tirés du livre "Homo Deus" de Yuval Noah Harari:

"Si vous faites entrer en ligne de compte notre croyance en la sainteté de la vie humaine, que vous y ajoutiez la dynamique de l'establishment scientifique et corroniez le tout par les besoins de l'économie capitaliste, une guerre implacable contre la mort paraît inevitable."

"Si vous êtes promu, mais que, pour une raison ou pour une autre, vous n'aviez pas de sensations plaisantes, vous ne serez pas content."

Est-ce que cette construction a un nom? Et doit-on utiliser l'imparfait après les "que"?

Comment: Une mauvaise traduction ? Les deux citations me semblent non homogènes sémantiquement parlant. "Si vous faites... que vous y ajoutez... et couronnez le tout...". Et "Si vous êtes promu, mais que vous n'avez pas de..., vous ne serez...". Mais je pense que ce mélange vient du subjonctif qui peut/devrait être utilisé avec "si".. "Si vous faisiez entrer etc.". Au présent, c'est une tournure qui parle mais ça ressemble plus à des maths: "si A est vrai (au présent) et qu'en plus etc...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Si vous ***êtes*** promu et que, pour une raison ou pour une autre, vous n'***aviez*** pas ...

No, the "que" clause, i.e. the 2nd "si" clause, does not necessarily require Imparfait. You could just as well go with Indicatif Présent.

It is just that Imparfait {aviez} denotes a less likely occurrence than is the case with Indicatif Présent {êtes}. The expression "pour une raison ou pour une autre" suggests that what you are about to describe as the 2nd condition is *more unlikely than likely* to actually happen.